# Unrecognized Tag Prefix or Device Filter in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, asp.net

I have a set of web controls that are in an assembly referenced by a website. I can build and run everything without a problem, however when I look at an aspx page where the controls are being used I get a green underline beneath the Tag Prefix.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="MyProject.UI.ControlLibrary" Namespace="MyProject.UI.ControlLibrary.Web" TagPrefix="ControlLibrary" %>
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <ControlLibrary:ListView ID="List" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

So in this example I'd get a green underline under ControlLibrary and when I hover over it it says Unrecognized Tag Prefix or Device Filter 'ControlLibrary'

The code was written in a previous version of Visual Studio, I have another assembly also containing Web controls and that seems to work fine.

Any ideas as to what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why this works but it does. When I change namespace of one of the listview control to MyProject.UI.ControlLibrary from MyProject.UI.ControlLibrary.Web and repoint the <% register then it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the reference to be in the `web.config` and see what error if any results?  Here's an example of the root `<asp:` tag additions for a location reference.  I like this approach because it keeps the pages cleaner as well if you're using the library much at all.  See if get the same result after moving the library reference.

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

**Update** - Based on your comment, try deleting everything in

`Drive:\Documents and Settings\[User]\ApplicationData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas`

or short version:

`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas\`

Comment: Yeah I'm a big fan of it too, I switched a while ago last time I was looking at this problem so that's actually the way I do it currently. Makes no difference.

Comment: Deleting the ReflectedSchemas worked for me, so thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Place the `<%@ Import %>` directive above the `<%@ Register %>` directive:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Comment: Excellent.  Just what I needed with my VS2012 SharePoint 2010 Application Pages issue with the Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what the cause is, but the ASP.NET XML parser in Visual Studio often has problems like these. Here are a few possible workarounds I have found, perhaps some of them will work for you as well:

- After opening the .aspx file, wait a little bit. It takes a moment for VS to parse the file and set up its IntelliSense;
- Try compiling the project **while the .aspx file is open and on screen**. A successful build often clears these issues up. If that doesn't work, try rebuilding the project or even the whole solution. And again - wait a little bit.
- If all else fails, put the tag prefix definition in the web.config file:

  ```
  <configuration><system.web><pages><controls>
      <add tagPrefix="ControlLibrary" namespace="MyProject.UI.ControlLibrary.Web" assembly="MyProject.UI.ControlLibrary"/>
  </controls></pages></system.web></configuration>
  ```

  Of course, try rebuilding, etc.

Comment: Good advice, those have solved other problems I've had, but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have found that if the control assembly is already registered to a prefix in the web.config and then you try to register it to a different prefix using @register, then you will get this error message.

Comment: Was this -1'd because the answer didn't happen to match the exact resolution to the question?  If you try this scenario, it does duplicate the conditions mentioned in the question.  I can see if I was totally off base in my reply but -1 is for when the answer has nothing to do with the question, doesn't provide specifics or is incorrect or otherwise misleading.  Otherwise, you might want to just leave an answer alone since it could be the cause of the problem in someone else's situation.