# Intellisense does not recognize Sharepoint.WebControl elements in a control template

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, intellisense

I am working with a project generated by the VS2008 Sharepoint template (VSeWSS). Currently, when working in the ASCX files that I have, IntelliSense does not recognize the imported namespaces. I'm uncertain what to do to address this.

**Note:** Per edit below, importing `SharePoint.WebPartPages` works fine, it's just `SharePoint.WebControls` that doesn't.

The project does build without error and deploys correctly. Removing the `<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint"...` line results in the expected "*Unknown server tag 'SharePoint:SPGridView'*" error once deployed.

I have found similar questions (ex. [Unrecognized Tag Prefix or Device Filter in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378372/unrecognized-tag-prefix-or-device-filter-in-visual-studio-2008)) however, the question and its answers refer only to web projects. In particular they speak of a `web.config` file. Something that is not created as part of the SharePoint template.

Suggested solutions and reasons they didn't work:

- Create a web.config file -- *File does not exist in this type of project*
- Add a reference to the dll -- *No apparent effect*

Further directions or suggestions on fixing this would be welcome.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
   Inherits="HelloWorld1.UserTableDoom, HelloWorld1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2ace7ea1e94310d3" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" 
   Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
   Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<SharePoint:SPGridView ID='fooGrid' runat='server'
   AutoGenerateColumns='false'
   DataKeyNames='user_id'
   DataSourceID='foo'>
...
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

**Edit:**
Interestingly enough, I can add the `WebPartPages` namespace and I it works correctly in IntelliSense.

I have also noted that when creating an entirely new solution and placing the ASCX file in it. The problem still exists. The SharePoint.WebPartPages works but SharePoint.WebControls does not.

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages"
   Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages"
   Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<WebPartPages:...>  -- works correctly.
```

Comment: What is the "VS2008 Sharepoint template" you used? From VSeWSS?

Comment: Yeah, the VSeWSS template (silly 15 char min).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same code you have to display an SPGridView, however have no problems with Intellisense. It does put strange formatting over the word `SharePoint` in `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` but works fine apart from that:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="QueryDemo.QueryDemoControl, QueryDemo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5434e690be8749f6" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebControls" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<SharePoint:SPGridView
    id="queryGrid"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceId="queryData"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    width="100%"
    AllowSorting="True">
      <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="ms-alternating"/>
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

Ensure that you have a reference to Microsoft.SharePoint in the Visual Studio project and try executing the code. If the grid displays then the problem must lie with Intellisense.

Comment: The page does execute correctly. There is a reference to the library in the References section of the project. I am unaccustomed to VS :/.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know much about VS's work-flow. But, the particular file is an ascx with which I am loading into my web-part.

Comment: @Danny: Maybe it has something to do with the project type. Have you tried setting up a web application project and copying the ASCX in there?

Comment: @Alex: I have recreated the file in another web site solution and it does not function here either. `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` simply does not seem to work. `WebPartPages` does.

Comment: @Danny: Try downloading the source to my CodePlex project http://spquerydemo.codeplex.com. That uses the SPGridView in a user control, within a web application. It might help to diagnose the problem. If you want to try e-mailing your .ascx file, use the contact link on http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/arangas or DM me your address on Twitter @alexangas, and I'll reply with my address.

Comment: @ALex: Opening the `12/TEMPLATE/CONTORLTEMPLATES/QueryDemo/QueryDemoControl.ascx` file gives the usual errors I have encountered within my own applications. `WebControls` exist and is recognized, `SharePoint` is not. There has got to be something I'm missing here.

Comment: @Danny: Must be an environment-specific thing. Not sure how much more I can help without seeing your machine. Maybe there is a Visual Studio or SharePoint install problem? Perhaps nothing to do with SharePoint at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Visual Studio Service Packs.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv -resetsettings
```

You may have to run as admin for maximum effect.

Answer (score 0):

I also make the assembly its own line and it works:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version......" %>
```

The ...... is the rest of the line.